# Is there a way to zoom an SWT Composite and its' children?

Tags: java, swt

I would like to develop a composite control which ideally would scale itself to its' allocated size.

I want to display a numeric value and 3 LED-type images. As the size of the composite increases, the font size of the value and the size of the images increase proportionally.

I seem to remember that there is something like this in .NET's WPF. Is there a way to do this in SWT?

(I know I could add a settings page and set the font size there. Just looking for a way to do it automatically)

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there is no built-in way to add zoom functionality. However, you can take care of that yourself with not too much work.

So what you can do, is use a `Canvas`, draw your `Image`s and text yourself and apply a scale to the width and height. This scale changes based on the mouse wheel movement.

Here is an example:

```
private static float scale = 1;
private static Font  font;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Image image = new Image(display, "button.png");

    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
    canvas.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener()
    {
        private int initialFontSize = -1;

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            Font tempFont = event.gc.getFont();
            FontData data = tempFont.getFontData()[0];

            if (initialFontSize == -1)
                initialFontSize = tempFont.getFontData()[0].getHeight();
            else
            {
                if(font != null && !font.isDisposed())
                    font.dispose();

                data.setHeight((int)(initialFontSize * scale));

                font = new Font(display, data);

                event.gc.setFont(font);
            }

            Rectangle bounds = image.getBounds();
            event.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height, 0, 0, (int) (bounds.width * scale), (int) (bounds.height * scale));
            event.gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
            event.gc.drawText("Some text here", (int)(10 * scale), (int)(10 * scale), true);
        }
    });
    canvas.addListener(SWT.MouseWheel, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            if (event.count > 0)
                scale += .2f;
            else
                scale -= .2f;

            scale = Math.max(scale, 0);

            canvas.redraw();
        }
    });
    canvas.addListener(SWT.Dispose, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            if (!image.isDisposed())
                image.dispose();
            if (!font.isDisposed())
                font.dispose();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 200);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 - looks like this works well for a simple example. I would need to handle nested controls and layouts (margin & padding). Guess that's do-able...